# JPA/Hibernate projection to an embedded attribute

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity, hql

I want to project to an entity with embedded attributes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "operation")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "operationtype", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)

public class Operation extends Model<Long> {

public enum MandatoryField
{

    USER_BE("userBe"), AGREEMENT_BE("agreementBe"), CHANNEL("channel"), OPERATION_TYPE("operationType");

    private String mandatoryFieldString;

    MandatoryField(final String mandatoryFieldString) {
        this.mandatoryFieldString = mandatoryFieldString;
    }

    public String getMandatoryFieldString() {
        return mandatoryFieldString;
    }
}

private Authorization   authorization;
private String          userBe;
private String          agreementBe;
private String          company;
private OperationStatus status;
private String          channel;
private LocalDateTime   creationDate;
private LocalDateTime   executionDate;
private LocalDateTime   processDate;
private Integer         registrationCard;
private String          operationType;
private Money           money;

...
Getters and setters
...
}
```

My hql query is:

```
final StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder();

    hql.append("select ");
    hql.append(" op.operationType as operationType, op.id as id, op.agreementBe as agreementBe,  money.amount as amount, money.currency as currency, ");
    hql.append(" op.channel as channel, op.creationDate as creationDate, op.status as status, op.userBe as userBe, op.company as company ");
    hql.append(" from " + ModelEntityUtils.entityName(Operation.class) + " op ");
    hql.append("  where op.id =:opId ");

    final Query<Operation> query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql.toString());
    query.setParameter("opId", idOperation);
    query.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Operation.class));
    Optional<Operation> result = query.uniqueResultOptional();
```

But, there is an error in projection:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not resolve PropertyAccess for amount on class com.rsi.nbemodel.model.Operation
```

Any idea? I'd like to project some attributes and some attributes are embedded but Hibernate doesn't like that.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Try to use `op.money.amount` instead of just `money.amount`? also ensure a setter named `setAmount` is available to set the amount. The same applies for `money.curency`.

Comment: Please also post the `Money` type.